# is uninitialized_copy/fill(In first, In last, For dest, A &a) an oversight in the c++ standard?

Tags: c++, standards, allocator

I like to know how things work and as such have been delving deep into the c++ standard library. Something occurred to me the other day.

It is required that containters (for example: `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >`) use the allocator specified for allocations. Specifically the standard says:

23.1.8

> Copy constructors for all container types defined in this clause copy
>   an allocator argument from their respective first parameters. All
>   other constructors for these container types take an Allocator&
>   argument (20.1.5), an allocator whose value type is the same as the
>   container’s value type. A copy of this argument is used for any memory
>   allocation performed, by these constructors and by all member
>   functions, during the lifetime of each container object. In all
>   container types defined in this clause, the member get_allocator()
>   returns a copy of the Allocator object used to construct the
>   container.

Also later in the standard it says (in a few different spots but i'll pick one) things like this:

```
explicit deque(size_type n, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

> Effects: Constructs a deque with n copies of value,
>   using the specified allocator.

**OK, so on to my question.**

Let's take `std::vector` as an example, the natural and efficient way to implement something like:

```
vector<T, A>::vector(const vector& x)
```

might look something like this:

```
template <class T, class A>
vector<T, A>::vector(const vector& x)  {
    pointer p = alloc_.allocate(x.size());
    std::uninitialized_copy(x.begin(), x.end(), p);
    first_ = p;
    last_  = p + x.size();
    end_   = p + x.size();
}
```

specifically, we allocate some memory and then copy construct all the members in place. Not bothering to do something like `new value_type[x.size()]` because that would default construct the array only to overwrite it!.

**but, this doesn't use the allocator to do the copy construction**...

I could manually write a loop which does something like this:

```
while(first != last) {
    alloc_.construct(&*dest++, *first++);
}
```

but that's a waste, it's nearly identical to `std::uninitialized_copy`, the only difference is that is uses the allocator instead of placement new.

**So, would you consider it an oversight that the standard doesn't have the (seemingly obvious to me) set of functions like these:**

```
template <class In, class For, class A>
For uninitialized_copy(In first, In last, For dest, A &a);

template <class In, class Size, class For, class A>
For uninitialized_copy_n(In first, Size count, For dest, A &a);

template <class For, class T, class A>
void uninitialized_fill(For first, For last, const T& x, A &a);

template <class For, class Size, class T, class A>
void uninitialized_fill_n(For first, Size count, const T& x, A &a);
```

I would imagine that these types of functions (even though they are trivial to implement manually... until you try to make them exception safe) would prove fairly useful if people want to implement there own containers and such and make efficient use of copy construction while using allocators.

Thoughts?

Comment: What are you asking? Why `uninitialized_`{`copy`,`copy_n`,`fill`,`fill_n`} doesn't take an allocator?

Comment: I am asking why there isn't at least an overload that takes an allocator, as this would prove useful in efficiently constructing data structures using custom allocators.

Comment: yes, but to be clear, I am not suggesting that the current versions which don't take an allocator be replaced (they are useful as well). I am suggesting that there should be overloads.

Comment: FWIW, Visual C++'s stdlib actually has an `_Uninitialized_copy` that takes and allocator argument and that gets used in the copy ctor of `std::vector`. :) Of course, as given away by the naming convention, it's for internal use in the library only. I'm currently digging through the standard to see if it somewhere actually demands something like this.

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate for the allocator argument (and its type) to have a default

Comment: From the standard description it looks like `uninitialized_copy` isn't atomic in the event of exceptions, while something like a `vector`'s reallocation must be atomic.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: the standard says `in the following algorithms, if an exception is thrown there are no effects.` which to me, means that it has to be atomic with respect to exceptions.

Comment: @EvanTeran: Thanks, I hadn't seen that. So the description of what the algorithm does is just a hint, rather than a valid implementation. I just looked at the GCC implementation, which does indeed keep a tracking iterator around for the deleting in the even of an exception (albeit with that spurious comma operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether we could call it an "oversight", per se.

No, you can't provide your own allocator to these specialised algorithms. But then there are other things that the standard doesn't contain, either.

@MarkB identifies a very good reason that the standard *shouldn't* do this (that the range has no knowledge of the container's allocator). I'd go so far as to say it's just an inherent limitation.

You can always re-invent `uninitialized_copy` for your needs, knowing what the allocator should be. It's just a two-line `for` loop.

Comment: try that it is simple enough. it becomes slightly more complicated if you want thread safety, since you probably want to do the whole thing in a `try`/`catch` and in the `catch` destroy any objects which succeeded so far..

Comment: @Evan: True. The "effects" snippet in the standard doesn't include handling for that, despite announcing that `in the following algorithms, if an exception is thrown there are no effects.`

Comment: Wouldn't that announcement require that any effects be undone if an exception is thrown?

Comment: @EvanTeran: Yes. That's why I said "true". :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, i overlooked that :-) Also, I said "thread safety" when I meant "exception safety" earlier (dunno what i was thinking when i typed that). I think that my meaning was understood though ;-).

Comment: @Evan: Yeah, I automatically fixed your typo in my head without realising actually :)

Answer (score 1):

If these functions were free-functions, I can't see any way that the compiler could detect allocator mismatches since the allocator type isn't retained by the iterator. This in turn could result in a variety of hard-to-find problems.

Comment: Harder to find than manually writing the same initialization loop directly using an allocator of my choice? I would imagine that it's about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is a (big) oversight, because information about the allocator is lost otherwise. The allocator is, in the current protocols, the only one that knows how to exactly construct an object in memory.

Now Boost includes `alloc_construct, alloc_destroy` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/alloc_construct.html
which at least can help a bit implementing generic versions of `uninitialized_copy/fill/etc(Alloc a, ...)`.