# Does it make sense to use std::uninitialized_fill() with any allocator?

Tags: c++

Does it make sense to initialize memory with `std::uninitialized_fill()` in a library when an allocator passed as argument by the user has been used to get the memory itself? I ask this because an allocator is supposed to have provide its own `construct()` method (other than the `allocate()` method), the implementation of which might differ from the standard one, so probably `std::uninitialized_fill()` is not always appropriate in all the cases.

To be precise, my doubts come from the C++ book written by Stroustrup (appendix E "Standard-Library Exception Safety", section E. 3.1), in which the author gives a possible implementation of a `template<class T, class A> vector<T,A>::vector(size_type n, const T& val, const A& a)`: the allocator a is used to get the memory for the vector, then `std::uninitialized_fill()` is used to initialize the obtained memory.

He also gives the implementation of `std::uninitialized_fill()`, which internally uses the standard placement new to initialize the  the memory, but there is no longer evidence of the `construct()` method of the allocator passed as argument to the vector constructor.

Comment: What's `std::initialize_fill()`? Do you mean `std::uninitialized_fill()`? The `initialize_fill()` function doesn't show up anywhere in the C++ standard, unlike `uninitialized_fill()`.

Comment: @Insilico sorry, it was a typo. thank you. I fixed the question.

Comment: This seems related to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727556/is-uninitialized-copy-fillin-first-in-last-for-dest-a-a-an-oversight-in-th, I do think that in actuality it is probably safe to use ordinary `uninitialized_fill`

Comment: Are you basically deciding between `std::uninitialized_fill_n(data_, size_, value);` and `std::for_each(data_, data_ + size_, [&value,this](auto it){std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(this->allocator_, it, value);});`? Looks like the answers so far are inconclusive, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the GCC implementation of vector, it reads:

```
  vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __value,
         const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
  : _Base(__n, __a)
  { _M_fill_initialize(__n, __value); }

  ...

  _M_fill_initialize(size_type __n, const value_type& __value)
  {
    this->_M_impl._M_finish =
      std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a(this->_M_impl._M_start, __n, __value,
                                    _M_get_Tp_allocator());
  }
```

So, it looks like the information of the allocator doesn't go away. However the code of `uninitialized_fill_n_a` is strange, it has two overloads (see below), one for generic allocator and another for `std::allocator`.

The generic calls, `construct` and the special for `std::allocator` simply calls `std::uninitialized_fill()`.

So, my conclusion is the following,

1) all `std::allocator`'s `construct`s have the same effect as placement new and

2) that cannot be assumed for generic allocators, or at least GCC `std::vector` doesn't assume that. (According to @Michael Burr you can assume this in C++03, unfortunately he doesn't mention C++11).

**therefore use construct (that is `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, pointer, value)`).**

My personal opinion (after investigating this), is that

i) `std::uninitialized_fill` is defective, in that should take a last optional argument (or another overload) with the allocator,

ii) as a workaround, inside your implementation detail you should have a `.uninitialized_fill(first, last, value, alloc)` function that does the job, including handling of exceptions (note below how constructs are unrolled with destroys on failure).

iii) Current `std::unitialized_fill` is pretty useless when you have information about the allocator (and basically you have to reimplement it.)

---

now the code referenced above:

```
  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Size, typename _Tp,
           typename _Allocator>
    _ForwardIterator
    __uninitialized_fill_n_a(_ForwardIterator __first, _Size __n, 
                             const _Tp& __x, _Allocator& __alloc)
    {
      _ForwardIterator __cur = __first;
      __try
        {
          typedef __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator> __traits;
          for (; __n > 0; --__n, ++__cur)
            __traits::construct(__alloc, std::__addressof(*__cur), __x);
          return __cur;
        }
      __catch(...)
        {
          std::_Destroy(__first, __cur, __alloc);
          __throw_exception_again;
        }
    }

  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Size, typename _Tp,
           typename _Tp2>
    inline _ForwardIterator
    __uninitialized_fill_n_a(_ForwardIterator __first, _Size __n, 
                             const _Tp& __x, allocator<_Tp2>&)
    { return std::uninitialized_fill_n(__first, __n, __x); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather call `construct`.

There are various reasons to provide a custom allocator, and a better allocation policy (using pools/stack storage) is not the only one.

I have also seen (and dabbled with) debugging allocators to help track down incorrect allocators usage in custom containers. It is also possible to use allocators to track memory usage, gather statistics, etc...

As such, `construct` might (or not) have additional effects beyond the construction of the object, and thus is not necessarily equivalent to a simple placement `new`.

In my debugging allocator, calling `destroy` without having called `construct` on that address before was an error (and likewise reclaiming memory without having called `destroy`), so at the very least I would recommend being consistent and pairing `construct` with `destroy` and placement `new` with an explicit destructor call.

Comment: `destroy`, not `destruct` (got bitten by this one a few times, unlike in french, it's asymmetric :).

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of any non-default allocator's `construct()` function is required to  have the effect of a placement new (per Table 32 - Allocator requirements in C++03).

So using `std::uninitialized_fill()` (which is defined as performing a placement new on each element in the range) should be fine - even if a custom allocator is used.

Comment: I think he's asking whether it's OK to *replace* the call to `construct` with `uninitialized_fill`, which is different. `construct` may have additional effects beyond the requirement.